# QFieldCloud does not work on app

Tags: qgis

I got an invitation to join QFieldCloud because I had registered a while back. I was able to sign in have a project in the cloud but when I go to the QField app on my tablet the option to open a QField Cloud project remains greyed out.

Comment: You need to use the beta version 2.x